# Rails 4 - Can't access local variable in partial

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to load a partial for each iteration of collection in a index.js.erb.  The partial is being used for the views of a google map marker's infowindow.  The controller is passing a collection called @sales_near_by to the index.js.erb file.

Now, I thought that I could just pass the local variable "sale" from the block below, but when I try this, my _sale.js.erb partial returns the error ***"undefined local variable/method 'sale'"***

My index.js.erb:

```
<% @sales_near_by.each_with_index do |sale, index| %>

    var infowindow<%= index %> = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<%= j render 'sale', sale: sale %>"
    });

<% end %>
```

For reference, my _sale.js.erb file simply has

```
<%= sale %>
```

As a test, I just passed the entire collection to see if there's something else going on, and it works

```
<% @sales_near_by.each_with_index do |sale, index| %>

    var infowindow<%= index %> = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<%= j render 'sale', sales_near_by: @sales_near_by %>"
    });

<% end %>
```

Since the above (with the other code below it) results in each iteration of the collection being given an infowindow of the entire collection object, I don't think there's something wrong b/w controller --> index.js.erb, so I'm a bit stumped atm.

Not sure why I can't pass/access a single iteration of the @sales_near_by collection in the partial... any thoughts?

Thanks-

Comment: quick typo - this shouldn't be the cause of the `undefined` error you're seeing, but you're using the `each_with_index` method, but you're only passing `sale` to the block.  You should be passing `|sale, index|`.  I'm actually surprised that you're not getting an `undefined` error on the variable `index`, actually.

Comment: @matt thanks, sorry I actually just typo'd in my post.  I did define |sale, index|... updated my post for correctness.  The block was using index, but I wasn't passing index to the partial.  Still befuddling me why this isn't working